# Usage of parameter from Parameter store in ECS not working

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-ssm

I am trying to create Task definition in AWS ECS. I've succesfully created task definition in which I used hard-coded environment variables. However I would like to use values from Parameter Store. hopefully this is option that is supported by ECS task definition but I think so because of the `Value type` option `ValueFrom`.

I've tried to define environment variable with name `TEST` with value type of `ValueFrom` and I've provided `ars:aws:ssm:eu-north-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:parameter/dev/ai/asd/test`. After I filled rest of information in wizard I've clicked on `Create` button and got error:

`The Systems Manager parameter name specified for secret TEST is invalid. The parameter name can be up to 2048 characters and include the following letters and symbols: a-zA-Z0-9_.-,`

I've also tried to use JSON config like this:

```json
// ...
"environment": [
    {
        "name": "TEST",
        "valueFrom": "ars:aws:ssm:eu-north-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:parameter/dev/ai/asd/test"
    }
]
// ..
```

Which showed error: `Unexpected key 'valueFrom' found in params.containerDefinitions[0].environment[0]`

So after that I've tried to use this one:

```json
// ...
"secrets": [
    {
         "name": "TEST",
         "valueFrom": "ars:aws:ssm:eu-north-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:parameter/dev/ai/asd/test"
    }
]
// ...
```

Can you point me to what I am doing wrong? I've tried parameters in parameter store in basic String value and also with SecureString type but it looks like it doesn't matter and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be in the `secrets` block, not the `environment` block. Only the `secrets` block gets evaluated to pull values from SSM Parameter Store and Secrets Manager. So the second JSON block in your question looks correct, except for the typo in the parameter ARN:

```
"valueFrom": "ars:aws:ssm:eu-north-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:parameter/dev/ai/asd/test"
```

You have the ARN starting with the letters `ars` when it should be `arn`.

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference-arns.html) for the general format of Amazon Resource Names (ARNs).

Comment: @paulg The environment block is for plain-text environment variables that you want to set. It has no bearing on values in the secrets block. I suggest asking a separate question on this site and including all the relevant details in your question. Also, I would expect an error if it couldn't retrieve the secret, not a null value, so including details of how you are looking at the value exactly would be relevant. For encrypted SSM parameter values you just need to make sure the ECS Task Execution Role has the appropriate permissions needed to decrypt the value.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I did get it working with just the secrets block. In my case the name I had was incorrect because the app was expecting a different variable name.